# Converting a date into week number within a materialized view

Tags: postgresql

I have a column that includes dates that need to conform to a certain standard, (week number starting at Mondays.)  This is a common function in excel, however, I have yet to find any literature on the topic for postgresql.  I would of course be doing this within an already existing materialized view as other columns are being altered and or calculated.

The current query is as follows

```
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW adwords_calculated AS
Select "Account",
"Week",
```

While the current date format is as follows

```
Create Date
02.01.2017
03.01.2017
04.01.2017
05.01.2017
05.01.2017
06.01.2017
06.01.2017
```

The goal would be to convert this into a view with the standard 01-52 week number format.

Comment: Post your attempt(s) at solving the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Use `extract` in your materialized view definition:

```
SELECT extract(week from current_date);

 date_part
-----------
        30
(1 row)
```